# Collecting Data from NDFD SOAP response

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I have written a small app that retrieves data from the National Digital Forecast Database [NDFD](http://www.weather.gov/xml/), and am currently receiving the XML response correctly.  I have noticed that although I can use the WSDL2Java tool in order to create the interface in order to request the weather data, when I actually use the interface to get the weather data it is returned as an XML string.  Is there a cleaner way to programmatically get the weather data from the resulting XML other than parsing it?  For example, are there Java interfaces available such that I could call something like weatherData.getTemp() instead of traversing through the XML itself?

Note that this is my first time using SOAP, so if there is something that I am obviously overlooking, please let me know.

Update:
Here is the [wsdl](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl) that I am using.

Comment: Could you give a link to the WSDL you are using?

Comment: Yes, I added it in the main post.

Comment: I'm going through this same thing as well....

Comment: I just used an XML parser to get the data back.  Let me know if you have any questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you use java
- the XML string returned by the invocation of the Web service operation is compliant with an XML Schema

then you can use [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/):

- starting from the XML Schema, XMLBeans generates java classes that let you programmatically traverse and manipulate a compliant XML
- you add the generated classes to your java project
- when you get the response from the Web service, you can construct a corresponding XMLBean object by parsing it
- finally, you can access to XML attributes (like "temp") by using java getters

Assuming that `weatherData` is a complex type in the XMLSchema, then you'll be able to to something like

```
String xmlResponse = getWebServiceResponse();
YourXmlDocument doc = YourXmlDocument.Factory.parse(xmlResponse);
doc.getWeatherData().getTemp();
```

Warning: this highly depends on how the XML Schema is structured, so the code may be totally different. However, XMLBeans is generally very easy to use.

A drawback of this solution is that if the XML Schema changes, then you have to regenerate your classes, and recompile your code. Hopefully this should not happen very often for a stable XML Schema.

Comment: Hi @MarcoS. I am having trouble installing XMLBeans for NetBeans. The instructors on the documentation were not very clear, and/or are deprecated as that version was likely to be for XP. I am on Windows 7. Could you give me some pointers on on how to install that library?